# adobe-flashplugin works for Chromium but doesn't work for Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

I have installed the `adobe-flashplugin` package from the partners source and it worked straight away for Chromium. Firefox is stuck to the old `Shockwave Flash 11.2` plugin, which I've disabled.

This page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash says the plugin should work for both browsers.

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04, Firefox 40.0.3

Are there any extra steps I need to take to add it to Firefox as well?

Comment: 11.2 is the latest Adobe Flash version maintained for Linux systems as far as I know... What version do you expect or what do you have for Chromium? I checked both `flashplugin-installer` which I had and `adobe-flashplugin` which you use and both show up as version 11.2 in Firefox for me. I don't have Chromium so I can't check how it looks there, but I would expect the same?

Comment: Chromium uses version 18.0 while Firefox uses version 11.2 so that is why I was wondering why there is a version mismatch even though both of them should be using the same plugin.

Comment: As @ByteCommander said 11.2 is the available version for linux systems...you may use pipelight  to use silverlight(instead of flash)  in linux for similar features

Answer (score 0):

Since adobe-flashplugin is no more supported by adobe the better solution is to use the pepper flash plugin for chromium :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

and then install the freshplayer plugin to adapt pepperflash for firefox :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

maybe you will have to activate the new plugin in firefox.

now you can remove adobe-flashplugin :

```
sudo apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash: 

"As of 2015-05, the old "pepperflashplugin-nonfree" is deprecated in favor of an official, maintained, one-step package called adobe-flashplugin, which works for Firefox and Chromium and derivatives. No terminals, no multiverse. "

That's why I thought `adobe-flashplugin` would be the right choice.

Comment: Yes you are right, i didn't know they were a new official package, so it seems to be the better solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working in Firefox, thanks to @Manchot0's previous answer.

To get `adobe-flashplugin` you need to install it following the instructions here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash which will make it work straight away in Chromium and then install `freshplayerplugin` in order to add it to Firefox as well.

As Manchot0 mentioned, in order to install `freshplayerplugin` you have to do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

Comment: This keeps the 11.2 NPAPI (for Firefox) Flash version from `adobe-flashplugin` installed but adds its 13.1 PPAPI (for Chrome) Flash wrapped by `freshplayerplugin` to your Firefox... It's still not the latest version 18 unfortunately.

Comment: I see. It's weird, http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ tells me I have version 18.0.0.233